# Why spring <util:properties> does not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and now trying to make a connection to the database.
I configured jdbc-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="simpleJdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- the DataSource (parameterized for configuration via a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer) -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" /> 

    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

and imported properties in root-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


  <util:properties id="appProperties" location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" local-override="true"/>


<import resource="jdbc-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

and while application deploys on server i have the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: 
Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${jdbc.driverClassName}]
```

but all is fine, if i use

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
```

instead of

```
<util:properties ...
```

Can someone explain me - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`util:properties` doesn't do property resolution, it just creates a `Properties` bean. See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties).

A `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean however does do property resolution. It's a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that manipulates bean definitions to resolve any property placeholders.

Comment: And another question: if i'm trying to use <util:properties /> and <context:property-placeholder /> it doesn't work either.

Comment: oh, i resolved this problem. All works fine. The point was, that I was trying to obtain property value BEFORE context loaded all properties. Just moved property-placeholder into root-config.xml from servlet-context.